# Duplicate entry '1-8' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with saving object with relationship objects.

This is short screenshot from database.

[image]

I have already couple of brands in database. I have lot of smarthfones as JSON data and I want to push it to database. Those smartphones are similar brands.

```
Smartphone smartphone = new Smartphone();

String deviceName = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("DeviceName");
smartphone.setName(deviceName);
...
//other related objects
...
String brandValue = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Brand");
Brand brand = brandService.findByName(brandValue);  // get brand from database by name
smartphone.setBrandId(brand);
smartphoneService.saveSmartphone(smartphone);
```

I get brand from database by name and set brand for smartphone. I save smartphone after included all needed object for smathpone. I got error
`Duplicate entry '1-8' for key 'PRIMARY'` This is related with brands because there is 8 brands in database.

I tried change cascade type to PERSIST,ALL, RFRESH and I got the same all the time.

```
@Entity
public class Smartphone {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Brand getBrandId() {
        return brandId;
    }

    public void setBrandId(Brand brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Brand {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brandId")
    public Collection<Smartphone> getBrandId() {
        return brandId;
    }

    public void setBrandId(Collection<Smartphone> brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you attach your primary key mapping on hibernate

Comment: i wonder what field(s) are marked as `@Id`?

Comment: Updated. But problem is that I have brand in the database already . I save smartphone with brand form database and hibernate wants to save it again. This is a problem, I think. I should use cascade type but I don't know which one.

Comment: Does your brandService create an entitymanager, load the entity, and then close the entitymanager?  If so, then the smartphoneService will have to do the same thing - create a new entitymanager - and then the brand entity is no longer attached to the entityManager, and so the smartphoneService does not know it is already in the database.  The smartPhone service would have to load the brand entity, attach it to the phone, and then persist the phone.

Comment: @Jamie probably you are right. branService has brandDao object where there is called brandDao methods. Basically saveSmartphone and other similar saving method use getSession().persist(entity); to save objects. I thought that it is just related with cascade type setup.